# Agile dashboard not importing - mismatch in options

Tags: dashboard

Need help for Agile dashboard installation. 
I am using following steps for installing Agile Dashboard 
http://tuleap-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user-guide/agile-dashboard.html?highlight=agile

First there is mismatch in options and I get following error message.

Also the option is asking path of the archive of the exported XML + data.

I am first time creating agile dashboard. Where I will get exported XML + Data

*******Please help*********

I am not sure If I am missing some basic steps

sudo src/utils/php-launcher.sh src/utils/import_project_xml.php 123 admin /tmp/MANOJ/planetearthings-scrumtemplate.xml
Usage: src/utils/import_project_xml.php -p project_id -u user_name -i path_to_archive

Import a project structure

-p  The id of the project to export
  -u   The user used to export
  -i        The path of the archive of the exported XML + data
  -h              Display this help

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is a bit out dated, you can now import an agile dashboard template directly from the web ui.

On a project, go in Agile Dashboard service, then Administration and here you can load the XML.